# DOM Selection and Range on a <video> html element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, range, selection

I am trying to find out how to make a browser display a selection for an video element?

An example html page below works as expected for an **img** tag: after finishing the **onElementClick** function the image remains selected.

I have no idea how to achieve the same with the **video** tag. Is it possible at all?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Range</title></head>
<body>
    How to select the video tag programmatically?
    <video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" controls="controls" onmousedown="onElementClick(this)"></video>
    It is easy with 'img' (click the image):
    <img src="http://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-mobile-lg" onclick="onElementClick(this)"></img>

    <script>
        function onElementClick(element) {
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            console.log("[Before adding a range] clicked: %s; selection.type: %o, selection: %o", element.localName, selection.type, selection);

            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(element);
            selection.addRange(range);

            selection = window.getSelection();
            console.log("[After adding a range] selection after adding a range: %o, selection: %o", selection.type, selection);
            console.log("[After adding a range] window.getSelection(): %o",window.getSelection());
         }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

A browser that I used was Chrome v. 28.0.1500.95 m